# how can I handle no spaces in phone number case for this regex

Tags: regex

I have a regex that parses out the three parts of a phone number input - but it doesn't handle some cases like 5555555555 or 555-2342341

https://regex101.com/r/kO3bG1/4

```
^(?:\+?1?[-.\s]?)(\d{3})([-.\s])(\d{3})\2(\d{4})$
```

how can I modify it so it handles these cases as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just added some more 0-1 quantifiers for the test cases you were missing:

```
^(?:\+?1?[-.\s]?)\(?(\d{3})\)?([-.\s])?(\d{3})([-.\s])?(\d{4})$
```

https://regex101.com/r/zJ3tF4/3